# Texture mapping on a quad strip

Tags: opengl, texture, uv-mapping

I have just started learning OpenGL and I am trying to map a texture on a Quad Strip. Basically, I am trying to create a parametric surface and I don't know how to map the coordinates. What can I do? This is what I tried so far and, unfortunately, it doesn't work.

```
public void draw(GL2 gl, GLU glu, GLUT glut) {

    Textures.track.enable(gl);
    Textures.track.bind(gl);

    gl.glEnable(GL_TEXTURE_2D);

    gl.glBegin(GL_QUAD_STRIP);

    double t = 0.0;
    gl.glColor3f(1f, 1f, 1f);

    for(int i = 0; i <= 100; i++){
        t = t + 0.01;
        Vector tangent = getTangent(t);
        Vector normal = tangent.cross(Vector.Z);
        Vector centerPoint = getPoint(t);

        Vector point1 = centerPoint.subtract(normal.scale(w/30));
        Vector point2 = centerPoint.add(normal.scale(w/30));

        gl.glTexCoord2f((float)t, 0f);
        gl.glVertex3d(point1.x, point1.y, point1.z);
        gl.glTexCoord2f(0f, (float)t);
        gl.glVertex3d(point2.x, point2.y, point2.z);
    }
    gl.glEnd();
}
```

Comment: Hello! Can you explain (or better yet, show!) how it isn't working, and how you expect it to work?